# What's the residue at 0 of the function 1/(z^2*sinz)

Tags: complex-analysis

I think that the function 1/(z^2*sin z) has a pole of order 3 at 0. That's because I can factor out z^3 in the denominator after expressing sin as a Taylor series. The other factor seems to be a power series, thus a holomorphic function, which doesn't vanish at zero.

Now I want to compute the residue at 0, but that seems tricky. If I multiply the function with z^3 I get z/sin z, and if I differentiate that quotient once or twice, I get expressions with powers of sin in the denominator, which is disturbing since it means that I can't evaluate the second derivative at zero. What should I do to overcome this problem?